# Login form doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

The login form just doesn't appear.

Firebug shows an error in jquery:

```
Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3
```

Relevant stack trace:

```
Error thrown at line 16, column 112430 in <anonymous function: append>(a) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js:
    this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)
called from line 16, column 117365 in <anonymous function: domManip>(a, c, e) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js:
    e.call(c?$(this[l],g):this[l],f.cacheable||m>1&&l<n?d.clone(h,!0,!0):h)
called via Function.prototype.call() from line 16, column 112339 in <anonymous function: append>() in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js:
    return this.domManip(arguments,!0,function(a){this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)})
called from line 1, column 5931 in <anonymous function: init>(r, g, f, j, o) in http://sstatic.net/Js/third-party/openid-jquery.js?v=41:
    l.append(p);
called from line 11, column 12 in <anonymous function>() in http://stackoverflow.com/users/login:
    openid.init('openid_identifier', customProviders, showSE, imgPath, true);
```

edit:

Just tried it out in chrome now, and it shows another error message:

```
Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3
    d.fn.extend.appendjquery.min.js:16
    d.fn.extend.domManipjquery.min.js:16
    d.fn.extend.appendjquery.min.js:16
    openid.initopenid-jquery.js:1
    (anonymous function)login:32
    d.extend._Deferred.f.resolveWithjquery.min.js:16
    d.d.extend.readyjquery.min.js:16
    d.c.addEventListener.y
```

This happens in stackoverflow but not in any other stackexchange site.

I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 and Chrome 12.0.742.100

Comment: We're looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this - that being said from the number of reports we're seeing, it's obviously happening.

I've reverted the changeset that cleans up the login page until I can repro the issue and resolve it, the login page should now work as it did previously.